# Exim - Sender Verify Fail

Tags: exim

I have domains on two servers: example.edu.au and example.camp

When I try and send an email (through Exim, SMTP) from pr@example.camp to eman@example.edu.au I get a bounced email with "Sender Verify Failed".

What could be causing this Sender Verify to fail, when the email is coming from one of my servers to the other server? How could I troubleshoot this?

I can send from example.edu.au to example.camp with no problems. Other than this specific example, I can send and receive from both these emails without any trouble.

`2017-01-24 23:39:11 1cWAg0-0000qw-MZ ** eman@example.edu.au R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=mail.example.edu.au [45.56.85.76] X=TLS1.2:RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1:128 CV=no: SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<eman@example.edu.au>: 550-Verification failed for <pr@example.camp> 550-Unrouteable address 550 Sender verify failed`

Comment: Your sender email address is invalid.

Comment: The sender email address `pr@example.camp` is valid. I can send and receive emails fine in 99% of cases. Only when sending an email from this address to an address on my second server does the sender verify fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
550-Unrouteable address 550 Sender verify failed
```

Means the exim server cannot resolve MX/A records for the domain and you have sender verification turned on.

More on this subject in the [documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_45.html)

If you can, log into the server running exim for example.edu.au and run `dig MX 
mus.camp`, although RFC spec says you can use A record or MX records.

TLDR; Sounds like a DNS Issue.

Comment: `dig MX example.camp` from the server running Exim for example.edu.au results in:

`;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.camp.                      IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.camp.               2869    IN      MX      10 server01-aus.emanwebdesign.com.
example.camp.               2869    IN      MX      0 server01-aus.emanwebdesign.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.camp.               2869    IN      NS      ns10.domaincontrol.com.
example.camp.               2869    IN      NS      ns09.domaincontrol.com.`

Comment: do those MX records resolve?

Comment: Yes, resolves to `107.191.56.29`. RDNS is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WHM(WebHostManager) then you can stop SPF check through the below path : WHM: Main >> Service Configuration >> Exim Configuration Editor >> Standard Options >> Mail >>Sender Verification
Try this on mail.example.edu.au server

Comment: Not using WHM unfortunately.